# Android: How to perform an action after the ui is fully loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which cointains a fragment with a vertical ScrollView

When that fragment is instantiated it retrieves an integer which shows the position it is supposed to scroll to

This is put in its arguments to be used when needed

in onCreateView method, this fragment calculates how many child fragments it should show and uses a transaction to add them to its content view, the fragment's layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/list.scroll"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/question_side_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/question_side_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="11">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/list.content" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works correctly

I have this code that calculates where the scrollview should go to

```
int y_coord;  
for (int idx = 0; idx < position; idx++) {
    y_coord += _children[idx].getHeight();
}
```

The problem is that I have tested most methods of fragment an during none of them does the child frigment have an actual height, I have checked the following methods so far:

1. `OnResume`
2. `OnStart`
3. `OnCreate`
4. `OnActivityCreated`
5. `OnAttach`
6. `OnCreateView`

is there some method during the fragment's transaction that will fire when the view is fully rendered?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

edit: as a side note I am using normal fragments not support ones, so I do not have access to OnCreateAnimation

Comment: onViewCreated() runs after the View has been created.

Comment: Just an opinion: maybe the height of your elements are computed while they are shown in the visible area of the scrollview.

Comment: see `MessageQueue.IdleHandler`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the `onViewCreated` method, or you could use a Global Layout Listener. The Global Layout Listener basically gives you a callback when the layout you attached it to is changed in some way. I use it when i need to hook into the view after it's been fully inflated and its sizes have been calculated.

```
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //Check here
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
     }
});
```

It's very important to remove it once you're done. Otherwise you're going to get many many callbacks.